# Trigger Audio onmouseover AND Change Image State the onmouseout PAUSE and change to a different image

Tags: html, audio

I am new at this so bear with me. I am trying to trigger audio on mouse over that also will change the picture at the same time. Then pause audio and change photos on the mouse out. So far I can change the images and the audio pauses but I only want to trigger audio for specific photos.  When I get the audio to work for selected images only the image doesn't change. I am so new at this and I am trying to copy some code of the internet but I sometimes don't know how to replace the values.

my audio file is "beep.mp3"
my image is 1.jpeg
Rollover state 1a.jpeg
Rollout State 1b.jpeg

I have 15 images that together form a picture.

This is for a homework assignment so it doesn't even have to be live. It just has to work from the index file in internet explorer.

This is what I have:

```
    <html>
    </head>

    <script
    type="text/javascript">
    function sound(surl) {
      document.getElementById("myspan").innerHTML =
     "<embed src="+surl+" hidden=true autostart=true loop=false>";}
     </script

  function play(){
       var audio = document.getElementById('audio');
       audio.play();
                 }
   </script>
     <span id="myspan"></span>

     <head>
     <body>
    <td>
    <img src=" 1.jpg " 
     onmouseover="this.src=' 1a.jpg '" 
    onmouseout="this.src=' 1b.jpg '"  /></a>

    <a href="{THIS IMAGE IS ALSO A LINK and it's the only image i want sound!]" target="_blank" HoverText 
    = styled.p`
    color: #000;:hover color: #ed1212;
        cursor: pointer;><img src=" 4.jpg "
     onmouseover="this.src=' 22a.jpg '" title="Bzzz" 
     onmouseout="this.src=' 2b.jpg '" /></a>
```

Comment: Your question has code sample which is broken and unreadable.

Comment: I guess that's the problem. I am trying to make a code where the audio plays when I mouse over an image and pauses when I mouse out. but also lets me change the photo on mouse in and mouse out at the same time.